# When I click submit on my php form the landing page comes up blank and it does not submit date to the database

Tags: php, sql

As mentioned in the title when I click submit on my php form the landing page comes up blank and it does not submit date to the database. It worked before (I must have done something incorrect) and actually occassionaly (extremely rarely) works, although I am not sure why. Below is the landing page for the form. And below that is the form itself. I am quite new to this so any help/comments are appreciated.

**Form Landing Page**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
    if ($_POST['title'] == '' or $_POST['story'] == '' or $_POST['city'] == '' or $_POST['province'] == '' ) {
    $_SESSION['error1'] = "All fields required!";
    header("Location: debate.php");
    print "issue";
    }
    else {
    include 'config.php';
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
    {
    $value = is_array($value)?
    array_map('stripslashes_deep',$value):
    stripslashes($value);
    return $value;
    }

    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep',$_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep',$_GET);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep',$_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep',$_REQUEST);
    }
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['story']);
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $province = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['province']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO comments(commentusername, commentcontent, status, debateid, city, province) VALUES ('.$name.','.$content.','0','1','.$city.','.$province.')";
    $result=mysql_query($query,$conn);
    $_SESSION['error1'] = "Thank you for your submission!";
    header("Location: debate.php");
    print "issue";
    mysql_close();
    }?>
```

**Submission Form**

Submission form coding.

```
<!-- comment form -->
<div style="position:absolute;left:600px;top:750px;border-style:solid;border-color:#970033;background-color:black;border-width:4px;">
<div align="center"><strong><font color="white"><b>Join the debate</b></font></strong></div>
<form action="cposting.php" method="post">
    <TABLE WIDTH="60%">
     <tr>
      <td>Name:<input type="text" name="title" SIZE="35"> </td>
 <tr>
      <td>City:<br><input type="text" name="city" SIZE="35"> </td>
     </tr>
<tr>
      <td>Province:<input type="text" name="province" SIZE="35"> </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td>Comment<br></td></tr>
       <tr width="80%">

      <td><TEXTAREA NAME="story" ROWS="5" COLS="30"></TEXTAREA></td>
     </tr>
 <td><input type="submit" value="Post"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I really apprecate your help. Thanks!

The code below is for the admin approval page. This is where the comments go when I post for the first time (and subsequent posts if I leave my browser open) but do not go after this.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) 
if($_SESSION['myusername'] == "Bobert") {
?>
<html>
<title>Discourse Magazine</title>
<head>
</head>
<body background="" style="background: url() no-repeat;  background-size: 100%;">

<?php
include 'config.php';

print '<h4>'.'Welcome back:'.'&nbsp'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'</h4>';
?>
<div style="float:left;border-style:solid;border-width:2px;"><img style="z-index:1;height:200px;" src="/favicon.png" alt="" /></div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Approving Comments (listed oldest to newest)
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}


if ($conn) {

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM comments where status = '0' ORDER BY commentid";
$result = mysql_query($SQL,$conn) OR die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
$capproveidid = $row['commentid'];
$cdeleteid = $row['commentid'];
print '&nbsp';
print '<div style="background: url() no-repeat;overflow:auto;padding-top:3px;border-style:solid;border-width:5px;width:800px;">';
print '<p style="padding-left:5px;">'.'<u>'.'<strong>'. $row['commentusername'].'</strong>'.'</u>' .'<br>'. $row['commentcontent'] .'<br>'.'<br>'.'</p>';
?>

<form action="approve.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="capproveidid" value="<?php echo $capproveidid;?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Approve">
</form>
<form action="cdelete.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cdeleteid" value="<?php echo $cdeleteid;?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>

<?php
print '</div>';

}
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
}
}
else{
header('Location: debate.php');
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely not properly formatting your `INSERT` query. By using double quotes around the entire query, you're literally sending `...'.something.'...`.

You can either do this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments(commentusername, commentcontent, status, debateid, city, province) VALUES ('$name','$content','0','1','$city','$province')";
```

Or this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments(commentusername, commentcontent, status, debateid, city, province) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $content . "','0','1','" . $city . "','" . $province . "')";
```

Either way, you can debug by adding `... or die(mysql_error());` after your `mysql_query`. Additionally, you can just `echo $query;` to see what is being sent.

Lastly, you should stop using `mysql_` functions as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) and use `mysqli_` or `PDO` which allow for prepared statements and prevent against SQL injection.

Comment: Great. Thanks njk. I am not at home now but will try it when I do. I have been racking my brain. Much appreciated.

Comment: Strange. This does not appear to be working. Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to add an error catcher and then I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks. I will add it in when I get home from work later on today. I do have a second piece of information. Occassionaly, after not trying to comment for a while, it will work. I can then make as many comments as I would like unless I close down the browser. Could this have something to do with ending the session?

Comment: Hello Njk. So I have added in the error function. As well I tried your suggestion and it does not seem to work. I was taking a look at which processes were running. When I shut down the php function that is running I am able to make a post and can continue posting until I shut my browser down. However no one else can post while I am doing so. And if I open another browser it does not work. I do have an approval admin area where I choose to approve or disapprove. When I post a comment it should appear in this admin area. It does not if I have alraedy commented. I will post the code below.